# Koin scope issue

Tags: scope, navigation, android-viewmodel, koin

I am building a single activity android app. As such, I am trying to scope my viewmodels either to a single fragment, or a navigation graph, unless needed otherwise.

My project is set up using Koin.

Although the viewmodel does persist between the fragments of my nav graph, when I move outside of those fragments, and then back to the nav graph, the viewmodel has persisted (values of variables have been kept the same, instead of being re-initialized).

All the fragments of the nav graph contain the same line of code to access the viewmodel.

I know this used to be an issue, but it is now supposedly solved. Any help?

```
class CustomerFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCustomerBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    val viewModel: CustomerViewModel by koinNavGraphViewModel(R.id.customer_nav_graph)
    ...
}
```

---

```
val appModule = module {
    ...

    viewModel {
        CustomerViewModel(get(), get())
    }
    ...
}
```